# Symfony2 Event that gets fired after service creation but before the controller

Tags: events, symfony

Is there an event that gets fired after my custom services are created but before the controller action is called?

And is there a full list of all events in Symfony2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the nice things about the DIC (Dependency Injection Container) is that the services are only created when you actually need them. This means that most services will be invoked and thus created from within the controller.

To answer your question, there is the `kernel.request` event that is fired before the controller, so you can use that.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a list of events, though I'm not sure if it is complete:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events

Comment: That list is very incomplete, there are only kernel events. What about doctrine for example? I am also looking for such a list.